# Trouble with phone number prefix validation / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation

I've got a validation that checks phone numbers by prefix.
When I call the function however, something inside the second loop seems to fail.
I suspect in has something to do with `otherPrefix`.

Here's my code:

```
function PhoneN(Phone)
{
    var number = document.getElementById(Phone).value;
    var zero = 0;
    var prefix = ["0", "2", "3", "4", "8", "9"];
    var otherPrefix = ["|", "7|7", "7|3", "7|4", "7|2", "7|8"];
    var boolian = false;
    var PrefixHolder;
    var PrefixHolder2;
    if(number.charAt(0) == zero)
    {
        for(var i = 1; i < prefix.length; i++)
        {
            if(prefix[i] == number.charAt(1))
                boolian = true;
        }
    }
    if(number.charAt(0) == zero)
    {
        for(var cut in otherPrefix)
        {
            var position = otherPrefix[cut].split("|");
            PrefixHolder.value = position[0];
            PrefixHolder2.value = position[1];
            if(number.charAt(1) == PrefixHolder.value && number.charAt(2) == PrefixHolder2.value)
                boolian = true;
        }
        if(boolian == false)
            alert("The Prefix number is invalid");
    }
}
```

Comment: 'but something in the loop inside is wrong' what goes wrong?

Comment: exacly i think i write something about it , gonna check the text i put again. the loop is executed but something inside the loop wrong.

Comment: Check your browser console for errors

Comment: console mark that line like a error : PrefixHolder.value = position[0]; and i dont exacly understand why , i mean i split it and then set it inside the position and split the position values one in the location 0 and one in location 1 , did i understand the concept wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code doesn't fail earlier, it will fail at the very latest here:

```
PrefixHolder.value = position[0];
PrefixHolder2.value = position[1];
```

And that is because `PrefixHolder` and `PrefixHolder2` are both `undefined` (you *declare* them, but you never *initialise* them), and trying to access properties of `undefined` is an error.

Also, it looks like an unnecessary complication to me. Is there a particular reason you're not just leaving them out entirely and do the check like:

```
if(number.charAt(1) == position[0] && number.charAt(2) == position[1])
```

?

Comment: ye yes yes, how i dont see that lol, no it just because i am dump , thank you my friend i gonna now try that and see. thank you guys

Comment: the function is work like suspected thank you again , i go now upgrade the conditions so not all of them gonna executed for no reason.